# Adding 'animate' to jquery dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, animation, menu

I'd love some help with this. I'm building a responsive dropdown menu that toggles between hidden/visible states depending on the browser window size. It's based on a jQuery solution that I found online.

At the smallest (mobile) version. It the menu drops down instantly when the click event is triggered, but I'd really to add an 'animate' functionality so that it opens gradually.

Not having much experience with jQuery, I am hoping somebody might be able to suggest where I can add an 'animate' command in my code.

Thanks in anticipation.

========= Here is the Javascript:

```
var ww = document.body.clientWidth;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav li a").each(function() {
        if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
            $(this).addClass("parent");
        };
    })

    $(".toggleMenu").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(".nav").toggle();
    });
    adjustMenu();
})

$(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function() {
    ww = document.body.clientWidth;
    adjustMenu();
});

var adjustMenu = function() {
    if (ww < 600) {
        $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "inline-block");
        if (!$(".toggleMenu").hasClass("active")) {
            $(".nav").hide();
        } else {
            $(".nav").show();
        }
        $(".nav li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        $(".nav li a.parent").unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
            // must be attached to anchor element to prevent bubbling
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("hover");
        });
    }
    else if (ww >= 600) {
        $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "none");
        $(".nav").show();
        $(".nav li").removeClass("hover");
        $(".nav li a").unbind('click');
        $(".nav li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
            // must be attached to li so that mouseleave is not triggered when hover over submenu
            $(this).toggleClass('hover');
        });
    }
}
```

================= And here is the html:

```
<nav class="main_navigation"> 

        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="item1.php"><span>Item1</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="item2.php"><span>Item2</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="item3.php"><span>Item3</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="item4.php"><span>Item4</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="item5.php"><span>Item5</span></a></li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

rather than using jquery to create a responsive design, have you looked into using a css foundation such as skeleton?

http://www.getskeleton.com/

Failing that I would recommend using media queries to modify the css of the nav depending on page size. In terms of the jquery,  you could use slideToggle

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I answered that on my mobile so didn't have a lot of space to type, here is the code I recently used to do a similar thing:

```
<div id="mobile_menu">
<p id="mobile_menu_btn">Menu</p>
<ul id="mobile_menu_ul">
<li><a href="exhibitions.html">Exhibitions</a></li>
<li><a href="artists.html">Artists</a></li>
<li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="social.html">Social</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!-- mobile_menu -->

$("#mobile_menu_btn").click(function () {
        $("#mobile_menu_ul").slideToggle('slow', function() {
  menuDown = true});

});
```

In terms of putting it into your code, you could try editing yours so it looks like this:

```
if (!$(".toggleMenu").hasClass("active")) {
            $(".nav").slideUp('slow');
        } else {
            $(".nav").slideDown('slow');
        }
```